# Automator use in Mac OSX 10.9 - environment issue

Tags: ruby, macos, path, automator

I have an Automator script that uses Ruby via RVM. My problem is the system default ruby is used and the environment is very basic. My question is how can I either set variables such as path and gem locations in automator or even better have automator use my default shell environment?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I wasn't ever able to get around this using the built in Ruby shell. I ended up using bash, sourcing the rvm.sh file in profile.d then calling ruby from bash. This worked as expected.